# Why isint opening a text file giving me desired output?

Tags: python, django, github-api, txt

I have a text file that I opened in python, but the output is completely different. I think this is hex.
Here's my code:

python:

```
class myClass:
    ...
    with open("token.txt", "r") as f:
            self.token = f.read()
    print(self.token)
    ...
```

token.txt (inside of working directory)
[image: my token.txt file]

Here's my output("there's no error"): `ÿþ1\x006\x00b\x004\x001\x005\x004\x00e\x009\x00f\x00c\x006\x00a\x00a\x00c\x00e\x006\x009\x001\x007\x00d\x00d\x004\x004\x009\x00c\x00f\x00b\x006\x002\x005\x000\x00b\x005\x002\x008\x003\x008\x005\x00a\x00`

PS: I doubt this will help but I'm using django and the token is for github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confident that this is an encoding issue. Please check `token.txt`'s encoding and use that to open it in your python code via `open`.

For example if the `encoding` is `utf-8` you'd write something like this

```py
with open("token.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    ...
```